# Display text after mouseover on image using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have written this Code in order to display the information after mouseover an Image. There are three images on the website, and each Image have the own text information:

```
var resOb = new XMLHttpsRequest ();
 window.onload = function() {
document.getElementsByTagName("img").onmouseover = 
function sndReq(0) {
}
document.getElementsByTagName("img").onmouseover = 
function sndReq(1) {
}
document.getElementsByTagName("img").onmouseover =
function sndReq(2) {
}
  }
 function sndReq(i) {
 switch (i) {

 case 0:
 resOb.open('get', 'info0.txt', true);
 break;

 case 1:    
 resOb.open('get', 'info1.txt', true);
 break;

 case 2:
 resOb.open('get', 'info2.txt', true);
 break;

 resOb.onreadystatechange = function() { 
 handleResponse(i); 
  } 
  }
 function handleResponse () {
document.getElementById("info0").innerHTML =
  resOb.responseText;
}
```

Sadly it doesn't work, and I'm not able to find out where the problem is. I need some help.

Here the HTML Output

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html lang="de"> 
 <head> 
 <meta charset="utf-8"> 
 <title>AJAX</title> 
 <meta name="viewport" content= 
 "width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
  href="lib/css/stil.css" /> 
  <script type="text/javascript" 
 src="lib/js/ajaxeinsendeaufgabe2.js"></script> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
 <h1>Zusatzinformationen</h1> 
 <table> 
 <tr> 
 <td><img class="img" src="img/b1.jpg" data-file="info0" /></td> 
  <td id="info0"></td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
  <td><img class="img" src="img/b2.jpg" /></td> 
    <td id="info1"></td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
   <td><img class="img" src="img/b3.jpg" /></td> 
   <td id="info2"></td> 
   </tr> 
   </table> 
  </body> 
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your handle response does not use i it has hard coded "info0". It should be:

```
function handleResponse (i) {
    document.getElementById("info"+i).innerHTML =
    resOb.responseText;
}
```

also you do not need a switch case you can do the same with:

```
resOb.open('get','info'+i+'.txt',true);
```

here is a link to the refactor fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pyr2447k/6/
try to see if that one will work.

Comment: Do you get any errors, is your onmouseover being fired? Also you might want to consider having the text loaded in when the page loads and not  ajax on mouseover. Unless you put caching in place so you don't make a call every single time the user mouses over.

Comment: I have an error Script1010: Expected indentifier ajaxeinsendeaufgabe.js (4,18)

Comment: Can you Show me how?

Comment: I just looked at your selectors and onmouseover and they are not correct. I will create a fiddle and add it to my answer with the updates.

Comment: Added the updated fiddle and was able to confirm the firing of the event.

Comment: I guess i Need to add the data-file Information in the php Code?

Comment: yes, I tend to use data attributes to pass values to my js code.

Comment: Nowi have the error SCRIPT5009: 'XMLHttpsRequest' is undefined

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest remove the s in XMLHttpsRequest so it is XMLHttpRequest

Comment: No error now, mouseevent works, but no text is displayed when i mouseover the Image.

Comment: you will have to post your html output for me to help with that

Comment: make sure you add the data-file to each image with the appropriate value. also use console.log to check the values of your xhr request

Comment: I have still the Problem that the text from my txt file is not displayed after mouseover